# How to check in an object has key in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following object let usersVal = snapshot.val();

The console.log

```
3TngNGbwMVhc5kJ2b3wAULEIP6g1
    Object
    photoUrl
    "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/ss"
    provider
    "facebook.com"
    signup
    1480596548396
    useremail
    "someemail@yahoo.com"
    username
    "James nan"
    __proto__


 c834vePyJ3SFVk2iO4rU0ke1cSa2
    photoUrl
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ff"
    provider
    "google.com"
    signup
    1480600290735
    useremail
    "3333@gmail.com"
    username
    "Ericel123eessdd"
    __proto__
    Object
```

I want to check if object has uid key. If it does I set some boolan value to true

```
this.users = af.database.object('/some-users', { preserveSnapshot: true });
    this.users.subscribe(snapshot => {
      let usersVal = snapshot.val();
      if(key in usersVal){
        this.userId = true;
      }

});
```

How can I achieve this in an angular2 component?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
let usersVal = snapshot.val();
if (usersVal["uid"]) {
    ...
}
```